# where to get the missing js file for the missing menu in 1.9.1 version?

Tags: menu

where to get the missing .js file for the missing menu in 1.9.1 version? Can someone please provide access to the missing file? In version 1.9.1 installation, products can not be access by visitors.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please explain what .js file do you need? What's the name of it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply missing a JavaScript file that is in the main Magento download then you can go to the Magento website and download the version you need.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download